# Angular2 redirect to external URL

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to redirect my Angular2 app to my OAuth2 authentication servers login page. This means that I have to redirect to an external URL.
I have tested this:

```
this.router.navigate(["/"]).then(result=>{window.location.href = 'http://external-url';});
```

This works in Firefox but not in Chrome. Isn't there any better way to do this? The `window.location.href` is the only solution I can find.

Comment: are there error logs in javascript console, when you try to do this in chrome?

Comment: works for me in Chrome & Firefox, with angular version 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me the the redirects worked in Chrome and didn't work in Firefox.
Try using the following code:

window.location.assign(http://external-url);